# Need help searching a MySQL db using a SELECT DISTINCT result

Tags: mysql

So I am new to MySQL and am having a bit of trouble. I have one table called book_genres and another called books.

```
book_genres
+-------+---------+
|book_id|  genre  |
+-------+---------+
| 1     | Horror  |
| 1     | Comedy  |
| 2     | Romance |
| 2     | Comedy  |
+-------+---------+

books
+-------+---------+
|book_id|  title  |
+-------+---------+
| 1     | A Book  |
| 2     | B Book  |
| 3     | C Book  |
+-------+---------+
```

I am using the following command to pull all the book_ids that have 3 selected genres:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.book_id, b.genre AS genre1, c.genre AS genre2, d.genre AS genre3 
FROM book_genres a 
JOIN book_genres b ON a.book_id = b.book_id AND b.genre LIKE 'Romance' 
JOIN book_genres c ON a.book_id = c.book_id AND c.genre LIKE 'Action' 
JOIN book_genres d ON a.book_id = d.book_id AND d.genre LIKE 'Comedy' 
GROUP BY book_id
```

What I want to do is now pull all of the book titles from the books table using the book_ids found in this search. I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this or not, but this was all that I could come up with.

Thank you for anyone who can help!

Comment: As you're not using any wildcards in your `LIKE` clauses, do they really need to be `LIKE`?  Also, given your example data above, your query wouldn't return any results.  There are no `book_id`s with corresponding rows for genres Romance, Action and Comedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a better approach:

```
select b.*
from books b join
     book_genres bg
     on b.bookid = bg.bookid
where bg.genre in ('Romance', 'Action', 'Comedy')
group by b.book_id
```

This selects all books that have one of the three genres.  Your query is unclear on whether you want "or" or "and" between the genres, so I assumed "or".

The group by uses a feature of MySQL called "Hidden Columns".  It acts like a distinct in this case.

If you need all books that have all three genres, you can do it this way:

```
select b.*
from books b join
     (select book_id
      from book_genre
      group by book_id
      having max(case when genre = 'Romance' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             max(case when genre = 'Action' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             max(case when genre = 'Comedy' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
     ) allg
     on b.book_id = allg.book_id
```

Comment: This is just pulling all books that have either a romance, action, or comedy genre. I need it to be only books that have all 3, not just one of the 3.

Comment: Second one is AWESOME! Thanks so much! Much faster than what I have tried doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT books.title

FROM books

WHERE books.book_id 
IN (
SELECT 
    a.book_id

FROM 
    book_genres a 
    JOIN book_genres b ON a.book_id = b.book_id AND b.genre LIKE 'Romance' 
    JOIN book_genres c ON a.book_id = c.book_id AND c.genre LIKE 'Action' 
    JOIN book_genres d ON a.book_id = d.book_id AND d.genre LIKE 'Comedy' 

GROUP BY book_id
)
```

Comment: This was my initial thought but the database is quite large and this query takes a long time to produce results.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll kick yourself as the quick and dirty answer is

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.book_id, a.book_title,
b.genre AS genre1, c.genre AS genre2, d.genre AS genre3 
FROM book_genres a 
JOIN book_genres b ON a.book_id = b.book_id AND b.genre = 'Romance' 
JOIN book_genres c ON a.book_id = c.book_id AND c.genre = 'Action' 
JOIN book_genres d ON a.book_id = d.book_id AND d.genre = 'Comedy' 
GROUP BY book_id
```

Swapped like for = seeing as you aren't using wild cards

There's a few other ways to do this I think, but none of them will be as easily understandable as your effort, and I'm far from sure they would perform any better, so unless the performance is hideous and can't be addressed with an index on the genre column of book_genres, personally I'd stick with this.